# Cyclic loading of custom cells Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I've been trying to get some response from stack on this issue for a while now with no success.

So i will try to be very precise.

I have an `uitableview` with two custom cell nibs. Data source for both are two separate arrays (questions array and answers array).
The first custom cell contains `uilabel` (question cell) and another one `uibutton` (answer cell).

On launch of the app a specific amount of question cells load up (depending on the amount of objects in the array) and after them the 1 answer cell loads up.

Here is the pic

[image]

after click answer2 - again the same procedure happens producing new question cells below as well as the answer3 cell

Don't know how to achieve that.

Thank you!

Comment: Try [tableView updateCell ] method. Or add new data into your data source and reload the table.

Comment: @Harvant S.  when i append the data into a datasource and reload the table it just increases the quantity either of the question cells or of the answer cells - they are never loaded below as new instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "increases the quantity" but not "new instances"?

Comment: @jtbandes here is the picture of how it looks like if i simply append the datasource http://imgur.com/dCFQtWh

Comment: I'll suggest you to make only one cell xib or class ( I would prefer class) with two identifiers. One for question and another for answers. Arrange your data according to you requirements and identify on run time that I want here an answer or a question. Get respected cell. Offcours your cell will be same but cause of different ids it will load different ui. You can manage ui according to your id in your cell class. Nothing much needs to be done.

Comment: One thing these ids will not be the 'cell identifier'. It will like a flag which help to identify what kind of cell is.

Comment: There are two methods for cell- one datasource method for load cell ( cellforrowatindexpath) and one another delegate method to customize your cell on before it display. These methods will help you. You can manage easily. ( I forgot what the other method is and I am currently on my phone)

Comment: @HarvantS. okay, thanks.

Comment: @HarvantS. actually i can't find the delegate method you've mentioned. and it's what keeps me from implementing your approach.

Comment: Here is http://stackoverflow.com/q/31988450/2071323

Comment: Sorry I was at somewhere in halfway of my journey.

Comment: It's totally fine. Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that hard as it seems. So, on the launch of the app, you load the initial questions and answers. For that you would need the number of required cells, say, 3 questions and 1 answer, totally you need to return 4 from the `numberOfCellsInSection:`. And, when the user taps(selects, press) the answer row, you just increase the number of cells on the table, if you have 2 questions and 1 answer on the next cycle, now you would return 7 from the `numberOfCellsInSection:` datasource method of the `tableView`. And so on.

Also, you can divide the each question-answer into the sections, if you want to have more organized way of achieving your goal. In this case, you have to increase the number of sections in the table, and return proper number of cells for each section on answer cell selection. Use `numberOfSectionsInTableview:` and `numberOfCellsInSection` methods of the datasource for this.

Don't forget to draw (set proper texts to the cell's labels, image if any) the data on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to reflect the correct data on your cells.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work the way i want it to. i'm doing it absolutely similarly (be it a simple `numberofRowsInSection` approach or `numberOfSectionsInCell`). yet the result - I'm getting is http://imgur.com/dCFQtWh

Comment: It seems like you have implemented the mentioned methods in wrong way. You have to re-check the implementation of the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method to make sure your returning the correct number of cells for the section. Also, check your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to feed the cells with correct data.